# Merging custom activity with preference activity on android

Tags: android, listactivity, preference

Is there any clean way to merge custom activities with preference activity or vice-versa ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using [PreferenceFragments](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceFragment.html) instead. I think merging Activities is not possible, but we have fragments now as well.